# ASP.NET Form value validation scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have the following html in my ASP.NET form. It represents a dropdown menu to let the user choose his budget. When the user selects a value on the list. A jquery code copies the selected value in the ProjectBudget hidden field so it can be submited through the form.

```
<p><label>Project budget*</label></p>
<a href="#" class="SelectionDropdownMenu">Choose budget value</a>
<input id="ProjectBudget" class="inputDropdownValue" runat="server" type="hidden" />
<ul class="DropdownMenu">
    <li><a href="#">5 000 $ or less</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5 000 $ - 10 000 $</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">10 000 $ - 25 000 $</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">25 000 $ - 50 000 $</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">50 000 $ - 100 000 $</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">100 000 $ or more</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">N.A.</a></li>
</ul>
```

This solution worked well for me in the past but I didn't have to make any validation on the field and using a unordered list gives more flexibility to our web designers over a DropDownList.

However I want to add ASP.NET validation to have the budget selection mandatory.

Besides using a DropDownList and use a RequiredFieldValidator. What are my options?

Comment: Is input `type=radio` an option? Also using javascript would work (if it is already a requirement - also for client-side validation). You can always validate manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a dependency on javascript, so why not use a standard `DropDownList` with the jquery ui [selectmenu plugin](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Selectmenu) or something similar which can give you the markup you are looking for and manages the `<select>` element behind the scenes. Then you can use the `RequiredFieldValidator` and have the markup you want for design flexibility.

As an added bonus, you kick the js dependency (at least for this item).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CustomValidator, set the ControlToValidate to the hidden dropdown. You can add a client script to validate client side..